# SQL Server 2008: setup user to mirror sa privileges

Tags: sql-server-2008, windows-authentication, privileges

I would like to setup my windows authentication login to SQL to mimic the privileges of the 'sa' account.  What is the easiest way to do this and have it applied to a dozen different databases?

Thanks,
Brian Enderle

Comment: You can give your login the sysadmin server role, but don't do it :)

Comment: care to explain why not?

Comment: It was just a tongue-in-cheek comment. Generally caution should be exercised with the sysadmin role (in a production environment) and should only be assigned to trusted individuals/groups who have the required experience to administer SQL Server. However, I realise that is completely company dependent... For example I've seen in environments where there are no DBAs, trusted developers are given dedicated "admin" windows domain accounts which are mapped to the sysadmin role. Just some food for thought.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"sa" is at the SQL Server Instance level: not the database level. You'll get full rights in every database automatically.

Basically,

```
GRANT CONTROL SERVER TO [mydomain\mylogin] WITH GRANT OPTION;
```

or

```
EXEC sp_addsrvrolemember '[mydomain\mylogin', 'sysadmin';
GO
```

The association between the 2 styles is [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175892%28SQL.90%29.aspx) on MSDN

But: are you *sure*?